# Google URL Builder Link doesn't work with JQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have made my url through google's url builder but when I follow the link with the ?utm_source=.... my slider (revolution slider) and many other elements to my wordpress site do not work. When I check the console I see

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Has anyone else had this problem or know how to fix it? It works fine without the extra tags in the url but I'd like to be able to track visitors from different sources. Thanks

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/jquery-is-not-defined-javascript-error

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.classymethods.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2'></script>` isn't being loaded

In your header.php file, is there anything specific relating to that line?

The source code is also formatted differently. Switch all plugins off, refresh with the long URL and see if it still causes an issue. If not, turn plugins on 1 by 1

It's as soon as an = is present in the URL that it breaks

Comment: Looks like it's w3 minifying the js. Is there a way to keep all js minified but keep it working with an = in the url?

Comment: W3 Total Cache? Do not use any of the additional optimisation settings for JS minfication when using jQuery and it should work fine.

Comment: With minify turned off it's about 90% there. (I think there's another setting somewhere in w3 that should fix the rest). Any suggestions on how I can minify css and js? I'm having the most difficult time doing this. Everytime I try a plugin it breaks the slider, counters, and portfolio.

Answer (score -1):

you should not have a space character in the url, for example, you URL should be like this:

```
www.classymethods.com/?utm_source=DOF&utm_medium=banner&utm_term=Classy_DOF&ut‌​m_content=Classy_DOF&utm_campaign=Classy_DOF
```

then everything will be working

Comment: Is there a space in there I'm missing? I don't see one.

Comment: There's no space character

Comment: you know, you have a space there encoded: its code is %20, so the page isn't accepting it. Its always so: if you write some false url (and UTM url is this kind of urls that emulate the url with GET request), you should not have spaces in it (and space codes) - otherwise you get what you get. So remove spaces characters from url - and voila: you've got working UTM url and site link :)

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, so... if my speach isn't clear - sorry. I really try hard to explain well...

Comment: It didn't work with no spaces - he has adjusted the minifications so it will work even with spaces

Comment: please go here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ and insert your url and click "decode" - you'll see how your URL is read by your hosting server.... there IS space in it, and its code is %20

Comment: minusing me for showing the reason of the trouble is pretty unfair, I have to admit :(

Comment: Even without the %20 I get the same issue. Thanks though.

Comment: pee2pee. I see, my fault. I'm minused fairly. Sorry.